# Matching Parantheses Using a regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression to match any string that satisfies the following criteria.

The string begins and ends with **a matching pair of** parentheses '(' ')'

There may be any number of parentheses within it.

For example my regex shud match :

**(**  ( p(x)+q(x) ) . (p(x) * q(x) )  **)**

but not match

**(**  p(x)+q(x) **)** . **(** p(x) * q(x)  **)**

How do i write such a regex

Comment: Are you trying to say that all the internal parenthesis must match as well?  If that is the case, I believe you would need to use a Push-Down-Automata instead of a regular expression to solve that, as a Finite-State-Automata (which define the space for a regex) does not allow for that type of a check.

Comment: To clarify my comment - if you are looking for a regex to solve a[n]b[n], where you have an equal number of a

Comment: dangit - stupid enter key - continuing: an equal number of a's and b's, then you would not be able to solve that general case with a regular expression.  Based on what you have described, it seems like that is what you are looking for (in a variation, of course) which would require a PDA.

Comment: To clarify, i am assuming that in my input all parentheses match. The only issue is that i want to capture those strings where the very first '(' matches the last ')'. That is, something like ( ... )

Comment: Now if i write a regex like ^\\(.*\\)$ _JavaStyle_ then i match also the strings of the form (..)(..) and not just ( .... )

Comment: That is my point - if all of the parenthesis must match, then you have  a situation where you want to prove that there are equal, matching elements of two characters - which is the equivalent of the a and b example I give earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please do a better search next time:  http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+regex+match+parentheses&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a

Here's your answer:  [Regular Expression to match outer brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546433/regular-expression-to-match-outer-brackets)

Comment: Yep, as the accepted answer notes - this is a simple algorithmic problem, not really appropriate for regex.  Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1):

Doing any sort of parsing like this using [regular expressions is difficult](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-rege) and almost always a bad idea. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). Oh, the horror!